# Cannot validate the input

Tags: java

I cannot seem to validate it so that it only accepts those 2 values, each time I input those one of the values it keeps telling me "Not a valid number Try Again" 
What would I need to do, to be able to select a certain number, or an alternative solution.

```
    double number = user.nextDouble();
    while (number != 1 || number != 2.50)
    {
        System.out.println("Not a valid number\n Try Again");
        number = user.nextDouble();
    }
```

Comment: `while (number != 1 && number != 2.50)`..

Comment: Comparing doubles using != or == is not good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
double number = user.nextDouble();
   while (number != 1 && number != 2.50)
   {
       System.out.println("Not a valid number\n Try Again");
       number = user.nextDouble();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

> This will always be true Because number Can't be 1 and 2.5

```
    double number = user.nextDouble();
    while (number != 1 || number != 2.50)
    {
        System.out.println("Not a valid number\n Try Again");
        number = user.nextDouble();
    }
```

> If number is 1 then
>
> 1!=1 || 1!=2.50 =>
>
> false || true =?
>
> true 
>   Same for All numbers

Use `&&` instead of `||`

```
            double number = user.nextDouble();
            while (number != 1 && number != 2.50)
            {
                System.out.println("Not a valid number\n Try Again");
                number = user.nextDouble();
            }
```